# Cancel adding several tracks into a playlist in Traktor

Tags: windows-7, traktor

I mistakenly added 10 tracks at once into a playlist in Traktor: is there any way to cancel the operation right after I added them, without having to go into the playlist and deleting manually?

I use [Traktor Pro 2.6.5](http://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/traktor/dj-software/traktor-pro-2/specifications/) on Windows 7 SP1 x64.

[image]

Comment: Why are you adding 10 tracks at a time if you don't want them?

Comment: @DaveRook I put them in the wrong playlist by mistake.